# How to save a molmap/density map on Chimera in mrc format using python script or Command line?

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-database

I know how to save molmap manually, but failed to do it using script; When I used command save or export, the file is saved as .py or .x3d, not in mrc. What should I do to correctly save the file using script or command line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe [bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for a question like this

Answer (score 0):

Using the Chimera [usage syntax](https://www.rbvi.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/commands/usageconventions.html):

**volume** *selection* **save** *filename.mrc*

Example:

```
volume #0 save data.mrc
```